# to disconnect the call programmatically in android for devices above Marshmallow

Tags: java, android

stackoverflow answers helped me to disconnect the call lesser than marsh mallow but not above api levels.

```
 Method serviceMethod = telephonyStubClass.getMethod("asInterface", IBinder.class);

                            telephonyObject = serviceMethod.invoke(null, retbinder);
                            //telephonyCall = telephonyClass.getMethod("call", String.class);
                            telephonyEndCall = telephonyClass.getMethod("endCall");
                            //telephonyAnswerCall = telephonyClass.getMethod("answerRingingCall");

                            telephonyEndCall.invoke(telephonyObject);
```

can someone help me for higher api levels.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean isMarshmallowAndAbove() {

  return Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M;

}

if(isMarshmallowAndAbove()){

  telephonyEndCall.invoke(telephonyObject);

}
```